# Kivymob test ad not showing on phone

Tags: python, kivy, kivmob

I have tried the test ad, but I cannot get it to work.
I have edited the Github example of Michael Stot to show the banner.
I have the admob appid and unit id, but I'm using the testid's
The Buildozer file contains the necessary changes and the apk compiles okay.
Herewith the main.py
I would like it if someone can tell me if the file is correct.
The code compiles okay, and the screen shows the 'Toggle Banner Add'. The toggle works, but no test ad shows.

```
from kivmob import KivMob, TestIds
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string(
"""
<KivMobDemoUI>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Screen:
            name: "banner"
            on_pre_leave:
                app.ads.hide_banner()
                app.show_banner = False
            Button:
                text: "Toggle Banner Ad"
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                on_press: app.toggle_banner()
"""
)
class KivMobDemoUI(BoxLayout):
    pass
    
class KivMobDemo(App):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    show_banner = False

    def build(self):

        TestIds.APP = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713'
        TestIds.BANNER = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111'
        self.ads = KivMob(TestIds.APP)
        self.ads.new_banner(TestIds.BANNER, False)
        self.ads.request_banner()
        return KivMobDemoUI()

    def toggle_banner(self):
        self.show_banner = not self.show_banner
        if self.show_banner:
            self.ads.show_banner()
        else:
            self.ads.hide_banner()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    KivMobDemo().run()
```